# Comparing Slick MappedColumnType using raw "base"

Tags: scala, slick

I have a custom column type, `UniqueId` that I use to map `CHAR(36)` UUIDS to a specific type. Because of how my code is structured, there is a specific column type for each ID (`CustomerId`, `OrderId`), etc. which also ensures we do not compare apples to oranges in the code (despite being the same underlying UUID).

However, in some cases we have a "generic" `targetId` in tables that can point to an ID in a number of tables. Because of this, the `targetId` type is simply `String`.

Using Slick, currently we do `t1.targetId === t2.customerId.asColumnOf[String]` to please the compiler. The problem is that this converts to `t1.targetId = CONCAT(t2.customerId)` which completely tanks performance (using MySQL) as any index and such goes out the window.

My question: Is there a way to tell Slick "just use this column as-is without doing anything", sort of a "raw" comparison, without resorting to raw SQL queries?

We tried `t2.customerId.asInstanceOf[String]` but it does not always work in our case (and is generally unsafe).

Comment: t1.targetId === t2.customerId.toString ? Forces the "cast" outside the db, and you can customize the .toString method in your types as needed ?

Not really an answer to your specific question though ^^

Comment: @C4stor Both `t1` and `t2` are tables in the DB and not values I hold, so `targetId` is `Rep[String]` and `customerId` is `Rep[CustomerId]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dig a bit, here's what I found to be working :

```
Rep.forNode[String](t2.customerId.toNode.:@(ScalaBaseType[String])) === t1.targetId
```

It generates a plain equality on the SQL side, with the trade off of being ugly as f*** ... :-D

On my side, I tested with a column for which I provided a `BaseColumnType[T]`, I kind of assumed it's what you were doing too.

Comment: A+ for effort, but I am not sure this is more readable than plain SQL ;)

Comment: No, it's not really readable if you're not really savvy about slick. You could wrap it nicely in a method "sql string compare" and forget about it altogether in the rest of the codebase though. And 2 years down the line, an intern will scratch its heads for days reading that :D